# Why the definition of Galois group in rotman’s Advanced modern algebra not considering repeated roots

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, galois-theory, symmetric-groups, algebraic-equations

[image]

The definition is provided in the upper figure. What if f(x) had repeated roots? Are the roots considered deduplicated such that there’ are less than n roots f(x) have?

As @reuns pointed out, I have got a wrong understanding on what a splitting field of $f(x)$ means (I do think the splitting field of $(x^2+1)^2$ is still $\mathbb{C}$... I think i can understand that $\mathbb{R}/(x^2+1)$ is not the same with $\mathbb{R}/(x^2+1)^2$, but I dont think that the splitting field of $(x^2+1)^2$ is $\mathbb{R}/(x^2+1)^2$).

So I resupply my constructively understanding of splitting field here:
Given $f(x)$ and $k$, we know that in the extended field $k[x]/(f(x))$, $f(x)$ take $z_1 = x + (f(x))$ as a root. So we can *repeatedly* divide $f(x)$ by $x - z_1$ to get $g(x)$. Repeat this step we can get a extended field $K$. And I think it's the splitting field of $f(x)$.

I think my understanding to $k(z_1, z_2, ..., z_n)$ is similar with the concept of subgroup generated by elements in a group. let $K/k$ be a field that $f(x)$ has all n (maybe repeated) roots. Then the image of the valued map, from the formal n-valued frac field $k(y_1, y_2, ..., y_n)$ to $K$
$$
\phi: k(y_1, y_2, ..., y_n) \rightarrow K
$$
, is a splitting field.

Is it wrong?

Updated again: The confusion maybe come from the proof below(theorem A-5.3):
[image]

the proof supposes the roots is distinct. I think **a more stable proof should be argued in the set of distinct roots. And then using the result of Sm is a subgroup of Sn.**

**And in fact the conclusion can be claimed stronger: the galois group is of subgroup of Sm, where m is the number of distinct roots of f(x)**. Right?

Comment: Everyone defines the Galois group of $f$ this way. I am not aware of a "repeated-roots-aware" Galois theory, short of Hopf-algebraic stuff (but that will give Hopf algebras, not groups).

Comment: It seems the OP thinks, no idea why, that $x^2+1\in \Bbb{R}[x]$ and $(x^2+1)^2\in \Bbb{R}[x]$ have different splitting field, ie. that $\Bbb{R}(i,i,-i,-i)$ is not the same as $\Bbb{R}(i,-i)=\Bbb{R}(i)=\Bbb{C}$.. Maybe he is confusing with $ \Bbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1)^2$ ?

Comment: @reuns yeah, it probably is my problem. Rotman argues in his book that the Galois group of f(x), which has n roots, is isomorphic to a subgroup of Sn. In the proof of this argument, root was mapped to another root under the element in the Galois root. But if the roots are repeated, shouldn’t we argue that it’s a subgroup of Sm, where m<n. And then use the result Sm is a subgroup of Sn? I am sorry I responded with my phone and unable to use latex

Comment: The Galois group permutes the multiset of root as well the set of roots so you have two embeddings of it, one in $S_n$ and one in $S_m$

Comment: Your description of the splitting field is fine. Given $f(x)\in k[x]$, factorize $f=\prod_j f_j^{e_j}$, pick a non-trivial factor, look at the simple extension $K=k[x]/(f_j(x))$ and repeat with $f(t)\in K[t]$ until your polynomial splits completely. As you see the multiplicity of the roots don't affect the process, we'll care of the number of distinct roots of each $f_j$ only when we'll construct the embeddings of the intermediate fields into the algebraic closure (thus obtaining the automorphism group of the splitting field)

Comment: @reuns So when we say k(z1, z2, ..., zn) is a splitting field of f(x) on k. We can tacitly suppose that the zs are distinct right? I think it’s hard to think about permutations on multi-index sets which contains multiple same elements. How can we say a root of one index is permuted to another index of the same root rigorously ?

Comment: When you reffer to $k[x]/(f(x))$ as an extende field you are assuming implicitely that $f(x)$ is irreducible over $k$. Otherwise $k[x]/(f(x))$ is NOT a field.

Comment: @reuns I think my problem maybe the notation of splitting field. For example (x^2+1)^2 ‘s splitting field is denoted as R(i, -i), or R(i,i,-i,-i)?

Comment: Note that if $a$ is a multiple root, dividing by $x-a$ is not enough since the polynomial you get is not irreducible. You have to divide by $(x-a)^n$ where $n$ is the multiplicity of the root.

Comment: The splitting field of $(X^2+1)^2$ is $\mathbb C$...Which is the same as $\mathbb R[i], \mathbb R[i,-i]$. The notation $\mathbb R[i,-i,i,-i]$ is NOT used usually, but it would mean the same thing as $ \mathbb R[i,-i]$

Comment: @N.S. yeah i understand it must be divided with the multiplicity. My confusion maybe come from the proof of that Gal(E/k) is isomorphic to a subgroup of Sn, where n is the order of f(x). I resupply the proof in the question and state my confusion.

Comment: The answer to the stronger claim is yes. The point is that the stronger result doesn't really give us anything new. This becomes much more clear when you start talking about separable extensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that an element of the Galois group is a field automorphism of $E$ which fixes $k$. For such an automorphism, it is irrelevant if the roots of $f$ are simple or multiple.

A polynomial has the same Galois group as the polynomial given by its irreducible factors to the first power, and for this reason people don't usually worry about multiple roots, since they are irrelevant.

Comment: thank you for youranswer. So when we say k(z1, z2, ..., zn) is a splitting field of f(x), we tacitly approve that the zs is distinct?

Comment: It is clear you didn't understand what is k(z1, z2, ..., zn) so you need to tell how you'd define it

Comment: @reuns I edited my question with my understanding of splitting field. Could you help with the points I misunderstood please?

Answer (score 2):

If $E$ is a splitting field of $f$ over $k$, that is just to say that $E$ is the smallest extension of $k$ in which $f$ decomposes into linear factors. These factors are by assumption linear, but they can be repeated. So $f$ can have repeated roots.

(Thanks to the first comment; for some reason I wrote "can't" and should've written "can.")